# Process a list with a limted number of threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to process a list with a limited number of threads, I want them to take turns, until the list is empty.

I tried the following  code:

```
import threading


class testclass(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name

    def run(self):

        while List:
            threadLock.acquire()
            print ('This is thread :', self.name)
            testclass.test()
            threadLock.release()


    def test():
            print (List[0])
            List.pop(0)


List = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

threadLock = threading.Lock()

test1 = testclass('test1')
test2 = testclass('test2')
test1.start()
test2.start()

test1.join()
test2.join()
```

But only thread1 gets to process the whole list.

```
root@user:/home/user# python3.7 test.py
This is thread : test1
1
This is thread : test1
2
This is thread : test1
3
This is thread : test1
4
This is thread : test1
5
This is thread : test2
Exception in thread test2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "test.py", line 15, in run
    testclass.test()
  File "test.py", line 20, in test
    print (List[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
5
```

How can I make them take turns on the list and not lock it until the list is empty ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Two observations: First, the standard 'queue' module is designed for this. I suggest you use it rather than list. Second, why have you sub-classed Thread rather than just instantiate a normal Thread and pass it the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could put a very small amount of time to wait so the other thread to have the time to "grab" the resource:

```
import threading
import time


threadLock = threading.Lock()


class testclass(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name

    def run(self):

        while List:
            threadLock.acquire()
            print ('This is thread :', self.name)
            testclass.test()
            threadLock.release()
            time.sleep(0.01)


    def test():
            print (List[0])
            List.pop(0)


List = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


test1 = testclass('test1')
test2 = testclass('test2')
test1.start()
test2.start()

test1.join()
test2.join()
```

output:

```
This is thread : test1
1
This is thread : test2
2
This is thread : test1
3
This is thread : test2
4
This is thread : test1
5
```

but if you want to process your list I will recommend using [Pool.map](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map):

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
import multiprocessing

List = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def process_worker(x):
    print(f'[{multiprocessing.current_process().name}]process: {x}')

p = Pool(2) # set the amount of workers

p.map(process_worker, List)
```

output:

```
[ForkPoolWorker-7]process: 1
[ForkPoolWorker-8]process: 2
[ForkPoolWorker-7]process: 3
[ForkPoolWorker-8]process: 4
[ForkPoolWorker-7]process: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

In threading at a time one thread will be in execution and starts another thread when current execution thread is in any I/O operation waiting. Please see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects)

> CPython implementation detail: In CPython, due to the Global
>   Interpreter Lock, only one thread can execute Python code at once
>   (even though certain performance-oriented libraries might overcome
>   this limitation). If you want your application to make better use of
>   the computational resources of multi-core machines, you are advised to
>   use multiprocessing. However, threading is still an appropriate model
>   if you want to run multiple I/O-bound tasks simultaneously.

Also here you are blocking all threads using acquire() method with **blocking=True**, default value. Please refer https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects

Even though with **acquire(blocking=False)** in your case thread switching never occurs as there is no I/O wait.